# How do I send a generated csv file as an email attachment in React

Tags: reactjs, csv, nodemailer

In my react application I want to be able to generate csv content and pass that as an attachment in an email using something like `node-mailer`.  All of the questions that I found related to this suggested using `fs`, but I can't use that client side so I need a way to generate the csv content and then pass that as the attachment once I send the email.  The reason for this is because I will be dynamically creating the data each time, and it will never be the same, so I can't use template files here.  I currently use `react-csv` to generate my csv files, but it looks like you are only able to download the file instead of passing the content to say another method, unless I'm missing something in their documentation.

The only problem that I see with using `node-mailer`, is that it requires you to have a file path, and doesn't look like you can just use generated data as an attachment.  If anyone could point me in the right direction, that would be great.  Honestly really stuck on this one, and can't find much on how to solve this problem in `react`.  Thanks!

Comment: Your problem is that you want to use node-mailer which runs on a node server, but for the client. The client cannot send emails. You'll need to create an API to send emails  which are received from your client app. CSV is just comma separated values. Just text!

Comment: @ChrisR that's my bad, I do send emails from server side using nodemailer by API currently.  So if the csv is just a text file, how can i generate this file on the client side and then send it through email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking more into what ChrisR said in the comments I was able to recognize that with `node-mailer` I would be able to specify a string as the content to pass as the attachment.  In this case I would just format my data into a `csv` string.  By doing so I can set my filename with the `.csv` extension and pass in the data string.  This allowed me to send an email with a `csv` attachment using `node-mailer`.  I was able to do so with a little help from the `papaparse` package as well.  Code is listed below, just in case someone needs to do something similar down the road.

myfile.js

```
...code above

// this would be called onClick on <button> element
TestEmail(){
        // this would be the data you want to send as attachment
        let temp = [
            {
                "Column 1": "1-1",
                "Column 2": "1-2",
                "Column 3": "1-3",
                "Column 4": "1-4"
            },
            {
                "Column 1": "2-1",
                "Column 2": "2-2",
                "Column 3": "2-3",
                "Column 4": "2-4"
            },
            {
                "Column 1": "3-1",
                "Column 2": "3-2",
                "Column 3": "3-3",
                "Column 4": "3-4"
            },
            {
                "Column 1": 4,
                "Column 2": 5,
                "Column 3": 6,
                "Column 4": 7
            }
        ]

        let to = MYEMAIL;
        let text =
            `<div width="100%",style="text-align:left;">` +
            `<h1 style="text-align:center;">Testing CSV</h1>` +
            `</div >`;

        let data = Papa.unparse(temp);

        $.get("/sendRaw", { to: to, subject: 'Testing CSV', text: text, data: data }, function (data) { });
    }
```

server.js

```
... code above

app.get('/sendRaw', (request, response) => {

  var mailOptions = {
    to: request.query.to,
    bcc: request.query.bcc,
    subject: request.query.subject,
    text: request.query.text,
    attachment: request.query.data
  }

  //console.log(mailOptions); Read up on NodeMailer for details.
  smtpTransport.sendMail({  //email options
      from: MYEMAIL
      to: mailOptions.to,
      bcc: MYEMAIL,    // sending to itself
      subject: mailOptions.subject, // subject
      html: mailOptions.text, // body
      attachments: [
        {
          filename: 'test.csv',
          content: mailOptions.attachment,
        }
      ]
    }, function (error, response) {  //callback
      if (error) {
          console.log(error);
      } else {
          console.log("Message sent");
        //console.log("Amount of people getting this email: " + response.accepted.length);
      }

      smtpTransport.close(); // shut down the connection pool, no more messages.  Comment this line out to continue sending emails.
    });

})
```